# Is there a way for message to have read status in quickblox group chat only after everyone in group have read it

Tags: quickblox

Me and my team are working on React app and are using QuickBlox for chat feature.
We have one on one chat and group chat features. I have searched very carefully in documentation but was not able to find answer to the question: 'Is there a way for message to have read status in quickblox group chat only after everyone in group have read it'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to mark a message as 'read' only after all occupants of a group dialog have read the message, you could use the `read_ids` field of response to the retrieve messages API call, as shown in this section of [QuickBlox documentation](https://quickblox.com/developers/Chat#Retrieve_messages).

This field contains user IDs that have read the message, for example: `"read_ids": [2792283,4374458]`. In this way, you can compare this array to the array of all occupants and if their length is the same, display it as 'read' on your UI.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.

Comment: @LazarNikolic you are welcome! If you have any additional questions, feel free to reach out to [QuickBlox Support](https://assist.quickblox.com/index.php?/Tickets/Submit)